# Создание двух параллельных процессов при запуске приложения на kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy, multiprocessing

У меня такой вопрос. При запуске программы некоторое время "висит" белый экран, и только потом открывается само приложение. Это связано с тем, что перед открытием приложения обрабатывается некоторый объем данных.
Так вот, хотел узнать, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы во время открытия программы был не просто белый экран, а, например, `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет нельзя. Белый/черный экран - это процесс выполнения вашего `main.py` от первой строчки и метода `__init__` до метода `build` класса `App`. И время, которое экран "висит" напрямую зависит от того, что вы там накодили. Если вы в методе `build` грузите 100500 `KV` файлов, то не удивляйтесь, что приложение долго стартует.

Comment: Но ведь можно в начале нарисовать картинку с вывеской 'загрузка' ?

Comment: Понял, спасибо.